# Rails rendering comments both ascending and non-blocked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is straightforward enough to display only the comments by people the user hasn't blocked:

```
<% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% unless user.blocking?(comment.user) %>
    <%= render comment %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It is also straightforward to display the comments in ascending order (the ascending scope is defined):

```
<% if post.comments.any? %>
  <%= render post.comments.ascending %>
<% end %>
```

But how do you do both of these things at once in a succinct railsy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just order the comments before iterating over them with `each`:

```
<% post.comments.ascending.each do |comment| %>
  <% unless user.blocking?(comment.user) %>
    <%= render comment %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can also combine the `unless` with your output:

```
<% post.comments.ascending.each do |comment| %>
  <%= render comment unless user.blocking?(comment.user) %>
<% end %>
```

By the way, `ascending` isn't documented anywhere - in what context are you using it? Do you have a scope defined for it?

Comment: Smashing, thank you. I should have mentioned I defined the ascending scope elsewhere (question edited).